# is it necessary to initialize whole model when using kfold cross validaiton?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

is it necessary to initialize whole model when using kfold cross validaiton?
I use kfold in order to analyze overfitting, every article that ı read says that model start from scratch at each iteration but most of the kfold examples doesnt use clear_session(), del model etc techniques. So ı am confused how my model start from scratch at each loop

Comment: Is your question about whether the full modeling process should be included in the cross-validation process (yes) or about the particulars of implementing that in some programing language?